# Can you call or use a Data Element on a Custom Page Code? like the variables in GTM

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-analytics

in GTM you can use {{element}} to use on your custom JavaScript tag so I was wondering if there is a way in DTM to call other data elements in your custom page code?

And also
I'm trying to get the value of eVar 1 and then output a string but haven't gotten this to work

```js
function MyCase(){ 
var url;
var txt = s.eVar1;

switch (txt) {
    case 'Forewords':
        url = "forwords";
        break;
    case 'Executive Summary':
        url = "executive-summary";
        break;
    case 'Educating':
        url = "education";
        break;
    case 'Social engage':
        url = "social";
        break;
    case 'Next generation':
        url = "next-gen-retirement";
        break;
    case 'Conclusion':
        url = "conclusion";
        break;
    default:
 url = '';
 break;
 }
return url; 
}
MyCase();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `_satellite.getVar('data_element_name_here')` to get the value of a data element.

As to your `eVar1` question: At face value, it doesn't look like you call `MyCase()` and it returns a value, but you aren't actually doing anything with it. What are you trying to do with it?  For example, you can:

```
// will output the returned value in the javascript console
console.log(MyCase());

// assign the returned value to a variable called someVar
var someVar=MyCase();

// create an on-the-fly data element
_satellite.setVar('someVar',MyCase());
```

Comment: is there some sort of way to get the value of a data element in the Custom Code? like `var txt = %dataelement%;` i tried it but DTM doesn't recognize it. I'm triying to do a switch case if the eVars value is `Forewords` in the link text than I would like the data element to output the string `forwords` so that I won't have to create multiple tags whenever the eVar has a different value like the sample above

Comment: to output the string `forwords` into `%txt_topic%`

Comment: To clarify the code above is the data element %txt_topic% so I'm trying to output a string depending on the value of the evar1

Comment: @sky yes, you can use `_satellite.getVar('txt_topic');` just like i showed at the top of my answer